# Memory allocation and OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory

I need to allocate many MB of array bytes into a MemoryStream object.

Sometimes, I get OutOfMemory exception when my application run as x86 on OS 32 bit system.

The cose appears like this:

```
MemoryStrem ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(myObject.FieldOfArrayBytes);
```

I would like to know if could be a best way allocate memory by write into MemoryStream within loop code, just like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< myObject.FieldOfArrayBytes; i++)
ms.Write(littlechunk);
// continue while all data are wrote.
```

Can doing some differents?

@EDIT
After reading other different articles, I think the best solution is allocate my array bytes into a list of memory stream. In this way, if I have not sufficient contiguos memory, I'll able to allocate large data in a fragmented memory section (virtual or physical).

Comment: It may help if the **source** can be streamed in (i.e. not exist all in memory at once). The **destination** will all be in memory at once (by definition - it is a `MemoryStream`)

Comment: Could you please share more of your use case and code? You might be also getting OOMs because of not releasing the stream properly.

Comment: Nope that will not help, might only make it worse.

Comment: You *may* be able to mitigate this slightly if you know the maximum size of the data in advance, by using [the constructor that allows you to specify an initial capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489(v=vs.110).aspx). This could prevent multiple reallocations of the internal buffer as it grows. Another possibility is that you are running out of large object heap space. [There is a way to compact that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) which *may* be worth trying, but this is not recommended.